# Check if one datetime is higher then another datetime

Tags: php, date, datetime, datepicker, compare

I have a question , i have 2 input boxes that are from the type datetime-local like you can see below.

```html
from <input type="datetime-local" value="2017-01-11T08:30:00"name="datemin" step=1> till <input type="datetime-local" value="2017-01-11T08:30:00"name="datemax" step=1><input type="submit" name="daysubmit">
```

Now i want to check with php if the the date from datemax is higher than the date from datemin and if the date from datemin is lower then datemax.
Does anybody know how i can do that?

I get with a post the values of the 2 inputboxes and i format the value from "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss" to "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss".

This is the php code that i have for so far:

```
if(!empty($_POST["datemin"]) and !empty($_POST["datemax"]))
        {
            $datemin=$_POST["datemin"];
            $datemin= str_replace("T"," ",$datemin);
            $datemax=$_POST["datemax"];
            $datemax= str_replace("T"," ",$datemax);
            //Here i want to compare the 2 datetimes
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) which are comparable and handle daylight savings time as well as timezones.

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2017-01-11T08:30:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2017-01-12T08:30:00');
if ($date2 > $date1) {
   echo 'greater!';
}
else {
    echo 'less!';
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/714507)